# Conditionally update state inside array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an array called 'info' inside state

```
const [state, setstate] = useState(
    {
        info: [{
            id: 1,
            name: 'john',
            status: pending
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'doe',
            status: completed
        }]
```

I want to check the status and change it to 'completed' and vice-versa on an onClick event

Answer (score 2):

I have done a stackblitz example for the same, you can refer it.
[Check stackblitz link here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-r834om)